# Python - Remove comma and square bracket from list in python - Insertion sort

Tags: python, string, list, join, insertion-sort

I have obtained the output for insertion sort but the **(' '.join(str(arr)))** function does not remove the comma and square bracket from the list. Any suggestions to remove the bracket and comma would be helpful

**Code:**

```
def insertionSort1(n, arr):
for i in range(1,len(arr)):
    temp=arr[i]
    k=i
    while k>0 and temp<arr[k-1]:
        if(temp<arr[k-1]):
            arr[k]=arr[k-1]
            k-=1
            arr[k]=arr[k+1]
            sortedarr=''.join(str(arr))
            print(sortedarr) 
          
        if(temp>arr[k-1]):
            arr[k]=temp
            sortedarr=(''.join(str(arr)))
            print(sortedarr)      

if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input().strip())

arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

insertionSort1(n, arr)
```

**Input:**

```
5
2 4 6 8 3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2 4 6 8 8
2 4 6 6 8
2 4 4 6 8
2 3 4 6 8
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 8]
[2, 4, 6, 6, 8]
[2, 4, 4, 6, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `join()` , you could directly print space separated items of list like this

```
lst = [1, 2, 4, 8]
print(*lst)
```

```
1 2 4 8
```

In your code remove that `join()` statement and just use

`print(*sortedarr)`

The reason you are getting comma and square bracket is because you are **converting the entire list as string and using join** instead of **converting items of the list to string and joining**.

Eg:

```
arr = list(range(6))

print(''.join(str(arr)))
arr = [str(i) for i in arr]
print(' '.join(arr))
```

```
Output

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
0 1 2 3 4 5
```